# How should a view controller interact with a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview

Can a view controller interact with the HTML elements contained in a web page that's rendered by a UIWebView?  Is there any access to the DOM, like there is in a C# form and a contained WebControl?

Comment: From the FAQ

>When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM API is not available. You can call a Javascript function from Objective-C by using [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:).

To get the value of an input field named "fname":

```
NSString * fString =[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementByName(\"fname\").value"]; 
NSLog(@"fString: %@",fString);
```

Comment: So if my page contains the following:
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

How would I access the first name field from the view controller using Javascript?